# Why does Photoshop's color profile conversion change appearance when source and target profile are identical?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-conversion, color-profile

Recently, I've noticed something in Photoshop I cannot quite understand:

I've got a Photoshop document (not a specific one) in e.g. sRGB, ICC-Profile embedded. Now, when <s>using 'Convert to Profile' with</s>  *soft proofing against* the same profile (so source and target profile are identical), no matter the other settings, the colors of the document change pretty strongly.

As both the profiles are exactly the same shouldn't the colors stay the same too? I'd really appreciate anybody telling me whatever I'm missing here.

Comment: If you convert to profile ... to the *exact same profile*, nothing at all changes. It does nothing at all, no new History event is added. Therefore, assume that's not what actually happened.

Comment: Why are you converting the profile, if it is already sRGB?

Comment: You sure you had the Proof colors option on! Before you converted

Comment: @BillyKerr I'm not, I was just curios as to why this happens. There's no reason (or even use) for doing that conversion, of course.

Comment: @joojaa No, I've double checked - proof is off

Comment: @Tetsujin You're right - I never really _applied_ the conversion, only used the preview. But I've noticed the same behavior in soft-proof and will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I can repro using 'Proof Colours' to the same profile - no clue why.